# How can I programmatically log into blogger.com?

Tags: python, automation, backup, blogspot

I want to automate backing up my blogspot blog.  How can I programmatically log in to my blogspot account and click the "Export Blog"/Download link as detailed here?  (Python preferred, but open to anything.)

http://support.google.com/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=97416

Comment: Curious... why do you want to back it up? Doesn't Google back it up automatically?

Comment: Good question, Two reasons:  (a) I have two years of writing tied up in the blog, and I like having a master copy in case the blog becomes inaccessible on the web. Google explains it well here: http://www.dataliberation.org/google/blogger  (b) I'm doing some automatic indexing of the blog contents and the backup format is in well-defined XML, so no need to do any ugly web scraping.

Comment: I'm guessing you've read about mechanize before? I use it to login to some simple sites, but I haven't managed to login to a google site yet...

Comment: Makes sense. Hope it works out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Google OAuth API](https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/oauth) with a RESTful library, like Requests, to generate a token you can use to access data from your Google account.

Comment: I forgot about OAuth. This is a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Requests library might work for this. I don't have a blogspot account, so I can't try this, but my first instinct would be to try this:
POST your credentials, store the received cookie.
GET the download link, passing in the stored cookie.

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/